# Maven javadoc plugin - how can I include only certain classes?

Tags: java, maven-2, javadoc, maven-plugin

Using the Maven javadoc plugin you can exclude certain packages - but I have lots of packages and only a handful of classes I want to produce Javadoc for.

Is there a way to include rather than exclude?

I would also like to do things on a class level rather than a package level as I have some classes in a package which need javadoc and some which don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I used the `sourcepath` configuration option to specify two packages containing the classes I wanted to Javadoc and gave classes in those packages that I didn't want to Javadoc default access.  Setting the `show` configuration option to public allowed me to choose which classes Javadoc was produced for by setting there access to public. Full configuration below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <links>
            <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/</link>
        </links>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <show>public</show>
        <doctitle>Foo API</doctitle>
        <title>Foo API</title>
        <bottom><![CDATA[Copyright notice]]></bottom>
        <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/foo/api;${basedir}/src/main/java/com/bar/api</sourcepath>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, this is essentially a workaround and I strongly agree with shek's comment that this should be an enchancement against the maven-javadoc-plugin as it is supported by the javadoc utility. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC

Comment: Note RCross' answer below.  It is the exact fix the OP requested, albeit added at a date much later than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, the ability to do this was added to maven-javadoc-plugin in Sep 2012, a good few years after the accepted answer was submitted!

Answer (score 18):

Since maven-javadoc-plugin version 2.9, you can do this in your configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    ....
    <sourceFileIncludes>
      <include>Foo.java</include>
      <include>Bar.java</include>
    </sourceFileIncludes>
    <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java/path/to/foo-and-bar</sourcepath>
    ....
  </configuration>
  ....
```

... which would build a Javadoc site only including the mentioned classes.

Comment: Thanks for adding this even though it had been answered.  Probably would have not found it if not for this follow up answer.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518220/maven-how-do-i-exclude-specific-source-files-from-javadoc

Answer (score 15):

Using the [maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/), you cannot specify specific java classess (though you can with the javadoc utility, see below).  However, via the the [sourcepath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourcepath) configuration option for the javadoc:javadoc goal, you can configure specific packages.  An example of this follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
        <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
        <links>
            <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/</link>
        </links>
        <show>protected</show>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/acme/foo</sourcepath>
    </configuration>
    <reportSets>
        <reportSet>
            <reports>
                <report>javadoc</report>
            </reports>
        </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
</plugin>
```

In this example, all classes under the **com.acme.foo** package (including subpackages) will have javadoc generated.

It should be noted that this Maven plugin is simply a wrapper around [Sun's javadoc utility](http://web.archive.org/web/20090708154943/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html).  As such, most of the documentation and configuration for javadoc holds true for this plugin.  See Sun's documentation on the javadoc [sourcepath parameter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#sourcepath).

In an area where the maven-javadoc-plugin differs in functionality, Sun's documentation for the sourcepath parameter mentions that it is possible with the javadoc utility to [generate javadoc for specific classes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#documentingclasses).  This capability is not available with the maven-javadoc-plugin.  An example of this is shown in Sun's documentation:

```
  C:> cd C:\home\src\java\awt
  C:> javadoc -d C:\home\html Button.java Canvas.java Graphics*.java
```

Comment: An example would add to this answer.

Comment: Example added per your request.  In writing the example, I realized my original answer was not correct.  I have since modified it.

Feel free to log a bug to the maven-javadoc-plugin requesting an enhancement to support the generation of javadoc for specific classes as it is supported by the javadoc utility.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC

Comment: It is possible to configure the maven-javadoc-plugin to include only specific files using the [`sourceFileIncludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourceFileIncludes) element.

Answer (score 7):

It's simply, when you use the configuration tag **`<subpackages/>`** from Maven2-Plugin, e.g.:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</sourceEncoding>
        <quiet>true</quiet>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <code>javadoc:aggregate</code>
        <code>javadoc:test-aggregate</code>         
        <doclet>gr.spinellis.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet>
        <docletArtifact>
            <groupId>gr.spinellis</groupId>
            <artifactId>UmlGraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </docletArtifact>
        <additionalparam>
            -inferrel -inferdep -quiet -hide java.*
            -collpackages java.util.* -qualify
            -postfixpackage -nodefontsize 9
            -nodefontpackagesize 7                          
        </additionalparam>

        <subpackages>
            de.interforum.gms.db.domain:de.interforum.sdr.db.domain
        </subpackages>

    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>javadoc</goal>
          <goal>test-javadoc</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>site</phase>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Specific configuration for the given reports ... -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Maven2 command is: `mvn -cpu -up -am -pl subProject clean javadoc:aggregate`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only filter at the package level. However Javadoc is only generated for public and protected types. If the types are default-scoped or private they won't have javadoc generated for them. Making them default-scoped means they are still visible to other types in the package.If you don't want javadoc, you probably don't want people to use those types, so this is probably a good scope to go for anyway.

The excludePackageNames configuration allows wildcards. So as long as you have a package name convention that allows this you can exclude the majority of packages.

Say you have these packages.

```
com.foo
com.foo.api
com.foo.internal   
com.foo.internal.core
com.foo.internal.util
com.foo.internal.ui
com.foo.ui
```

and you only want to expose foo, foo.api and foo.ui, this pattern will work:

```
<excludePackageNames>com.foo.internal.*:com.foo.bob</excludePackageNames>
```

You could alternatively move the offending types into separate packages, but this is not a good reason to do so.

What is the issue with generating javadoc for these types?

Comment: While you may be on the right track to question the need to only specify javadoc for specific classes, it is possible to configure the maven-javadoc-plugin to only generate javadoc for specific classes.  See my answer below.

Comment: Rich -- feel free to remove your +1. In coming up with the example configuration, I realized that the maven-javadoc-plugin does not honor all of the functionality of the javadoc utility.  So, I jumped the gun.  I did add an example on how to configure the plugin to include only specific packages, which I believe is a nice complement to your answer on excluding specific packages.

+1 to you as well.