# Maven: How do I exclude specific source files from javadoc?

Tags: maven, javadoc

I need to exclude specific source files (NOT just packages) from Javadoc using Maven. The <excludePackageNames> setting will not work for me: it only allows you to exclude certain packages. There's a <sourceFileExcludes> setting that has basically no documentation in the way of usage examples. It just says:

"sourceFileExcludes: exclude filters on the source files. These are ignored if you specify subpackages or subpackage excludes."

So, basically, I need to ignore all Java files that start with Mock, and also all Java files in two packages. Since sourceFileExcludes are ignored if I specify excludePackageNames, I can't combine them. So I tried this:

```
<sourceFileExcludes>
    <exclude>net/my/packagename/mock</exclude>
    <exclude>net/my/packagename/samples</exclude>
    <exclude>**/Mock*.java</exclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```

But it did not work. None of the intended files were excluded.

Anybody know how to use sourceFileExcludes?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13465674/1281433) is a bit older, and has a similar problem, but fewer details.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm in a similar situation, and if you found an answer, it'd be great to hear it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never found a fix for this. I ended up reorganizing my project and put samples in a separate module (which, really, was the "right way"). I then simply didn't generate Javadoc for that module. Sorry. :-/

Comment: Aww, that's kind of disappointing. I ended up doing the same thing, too.  I may end up trying to find a mailing list for the Javadoc plugin, and asking there. If I do, I'll report back here.

Comment: Not sure it would work anyway, there is a bug with this tag: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-365?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: seems to work in 2.10.1

Comment: Is there a way to exclude/ignore methods (not just files/classes)? I tried using `@exclude` and it didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might just not be working at the moment. There is bug logged in the plugin issue tracker - [MJAVADOC-365](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508094224/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAVADOC-365)

Comment: Thanks for this. I searched that issue tracker a while ago and couldn't find the bug. I meant to file one, but never got around to it. Now I don't have to! It's a shame that bug hasn't even been responded to in over a year (AND IT HAS A PATCH!).

Comment: I agree, I am running into the same problem :-(

Comment: I submitted an enhanced patch along with a test case and it has been applied. Looks like it will be in version 2.11 of the plugin.

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in 2.10.2

Comment: @hoshposh Yes, it was fixed in 2.10.2. Than you!

Comment: Is there a way to exclude/ignore methods (not just files/classes)? I tried using `@exclude` and it didn't work

Answer (score 7):

And what about this?

```xml
<sourceFileExcludes>
    <exclude>net/my/packagename/mock/*.java</exclude>
    <exclude>net/my/packagename/samples/*.java</exclude>
    <exclude>**Mock*.java</exclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```

Comment: We're getting closer: `<sourceFileExcludes>
    <exclude>net/nicholaswilliams/java/mock/**</exclude>
    <exclude>net/nicholaswilliams/java/licensing/mock/**</exclude>
    <exclude>net/nicholaswilliams/java/licensing/samples/**</exclude>
    <exclude>**Mock*.java</exclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>` The package excludes are preventing my packages from appearing, so that's good. But there's that one stubborn file (that unfortunately I can't move) that just won't exclude with the fourth exclude. I have even tried a very explicit `<exclude>net/my/packagename/MockLicenseHelper.java</exclude>`!

Comment: did you try to change the order ? i.e. <exclude>**Mock*.java</exclude> first

Comment: I tried it now. Didn't make a difference with it at the top. I'm beginning to think that this is a bug.

Comment: One last thing : be sure to clean your javadoc output directory before running + double check for typo errors

Comment: Yea, I'm cleaning the entire output directory and then running the entire Maven build again, with no change. I also ran Maven `-debug`, and at Javadoc time it lists all of the exclusion rules and all four of my rules are listed. I copied and pasted the package names and class name, so no typo errors there. It's just like it's not applying the rule.

Comment: @NickWilliams I've got the same situation, and while `<exclude>full/package/directory/*.java</exclude>` successfully hides excludes in that package, including `Foo`, `<exclude>full/package/directory/Foo.java</exclude>` _doesn't_.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude/ignore methods (not just files/classes)? I tried using `@exclude` and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify sourcepath also. Then sourceFileExcludes will work.

```html
<sourceFileExcludes>
  <exclude>CryptoUtils.java</exclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
<sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/sdk/entity;${basedir}/src/main/java/com/sdk/main;${basedir}/src/main/java/com/sdk/util</sourcepath>
```

Note :

CryptoUtils is inside "/src/main/java/com/sdk/util"

Answer (score -5):

```
  <sourceFileIncludes>
    <includes>com/cod/user/**</includes>

   </sourceFileIncludes>
  <sourceFileExcludes>
 <exclude>com/cod/user/impl/**</exclude>
```

includes you want ,exclude else