# maven-javadoc-plugin sourceFileExcludes not working

Tags: maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm not too sure what is the right way to use this tag, but I use it like this:

```
<sourceFileExcludes>
  <exclude></exclude>
  <exclude></exclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```

It doesn't work at all. It seems that there was a known bug in maven that this tag won't work as I found these threads:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223872/3209177

But that was a while ago. I didn't find much useful information on maven website as well.

So how can we exclude certain source files / classes while we build javadoc using maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

First, there was an known bug as tracked in this page: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-365
And the patch went into the plugin 2.10.2. So after that version, the bug is fixed. However, I was using some earlier version.

Second, use this schema:

```
<sourceFileExcludes>
  <sourceFileExclude></sourceFileExclude>
  <sourceFileExclude></sourceFileExclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```

To exclude file.

Third, in the sourceFileExclude, I used someClass.java, this is probably not right. Instead, I used someClass.* and this works for me.

Comment: Upvoted. `someClass.java` works for me in version 2.10.3, e.g. `<sourceFileExclude>java/util/Random.java</sourceFileExclude>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern. It excludes the files irregardless of their package structure. More information [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12717016/MJAVADOC-365-REC-2014-10-09.patch)

```
<sourceFileExcludes>
    <exclude>**/AppTest.java</exclude>
    <exclude>**/Tester.java</exclude>
</sourceFileExcludes>
```